# Processing3 Write Text Straight to Screen

Tags: processing

In Processing, I have a 3D scene where the camera moves a lot. Normally, if I wanted to render visible text, I'd have to rotate the text so that its normal aligns with the vector between the camera position and destination. This seems overkill for what I want: I simply want 2D text to display on the screen, like subtitles.

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do this? I know the `set` function lets you manually set the value of pixels without interference from transformation matrices, and I figure there should be a way to do this with text, although I can't find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: A [mcve] showing what you are trying to achieve might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. In the future, try to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you're stuck on.

You pretty much already know what to do:

> I know the set function lets you manually set the value of pixels without interference from transformation matrices, and I figure there should be a way to do this with text

You could use a `PGraphics` buffer that you draw the text to, then just draw that buffer to the screen. Something like this:

```
PGraphics pg;

void setup(){
 size(500, 500, P3D); 
 pg = createGraphics(100, 50);
 pg.beginDraw();
 pg.background(255, 0, 0);
 pg.text("hello", 10, 20);
 pg.endDraw();
}

void draw(){
 background(128);

 pushMatrix();
 translate(mouseX, mouseY, 100);
 sphere(100);
 popMatrix();

 set(0, 0, pg);
}
```

[image: text on sphere]